# Replacing values in a Pandas data frame with the order of their columns

Tags: python, list, pandas

How can we replace specific values in a data frame such that the replacements are equal to the order of the ith column where those specific values reside? For example I have this DF:

```
A  B  C
0  0  1
1  0  0 
1  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  1
```

Replacing all ones in this data frame with the order of the ith column (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc) where the 1's reside, so that it loos like this:

```
A  B  C
0  0  3
1  0  0 
1  0  0
0  2  0
1  0  3
```

That is what I thought would work, but it did not:

```
 DF_2= [(0 if i== 0 else j  for i in DF.iloc[:,j]  ) for j in range(DF.shape[1]) ]
```

Comment: What did your code return?  Please include that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only `1` and `0` values you can multiple numpy array converted by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) with `np.arrange`:

```
print (np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1))
[1 2 3]


print (df.values * np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1))
[[0 0 3]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [1 0 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values * np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1),
                  index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  2  0
4  1  0  3
```

More general solution, (if `0` and another numeric) is convert values to bool:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  4
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  6  0
4  1  0  1

df = pd.DataFrame(df.astype(bool).values * np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1),
                  index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  2  0
4  1  0  3
```

Thank you for another solutions ([Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) and [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462637/replacing-values-in-a-pandas-data-frame-with-the-order-of-thier-columns/45462720#comment77886308_45462720)):

```
df = df.replace({col: {1: n} for n, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 2)})
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  2  0
4  1  0  3
```

---

```
df = df * np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  2  0
4  1  0  3
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 100
cols = ['col' + str(i) for i in range(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=(100000,N)), columns=cols)
[100000 rows x 100 columns]
#print (df)


In [101]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.values * np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop

In [102]: %timeit df.replace({col: {1: n} for n, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 2)})
1 loop, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop

In [103]: %timeit df * np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop

#Wen solution
In [104]: %timeit (df.mul(list(range(1, len(df.columns)+1))))
10 loops, best of 3: 38.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Or `df.replace({col: {1: n} for n, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 2)})`

Comment: AFAIK we can do it directly without converting it to numpy array (`.values`): `df * np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)`

Comment: @JonClements - Give me some time :)

Comment: @JonClements - `replace` is slowiest.

Comment: @jezrael not surprised - figured it's got more work to do (and could do more than a simple 1->col idx if needed - thanks for checking :)

Comment: @jezrael ...Pandas 9,999 Score :o

Comment: @jezrael if you can ,could you please test the running time for my solution , just curious about it .

Comment: @Wen - It was added

Comment: @Wen - I use `len(df.columns)` because fastest, but there is difference in `us` only :)

Comment: Your answer always earn my upovte ~:)

Answer (score 2):

or you can try this .(PS: you can using `range` to generate the `list` :`list(range(1,df1.shape[1]+1))`
)

```
df.mul([1,2,3])
Out[433]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  2  0
4  1  0  3
```